# I import a header but it's not importing my source code

Tags: c, include

I'm trying to import a module but when I build and run it says: undefined reference to `addNum`. And it's make 2 hours I'm trying to find why can someone please help please, I'm a beginner.

Main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "testFunction.h"

int main()
{
    int result = addNum(12);
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

testFunction.h:

```
#ifndef TESTFUNCTION_H_INCLUDED
#define TESTFUNCTION_H_INCLUDED

int addNum(int num);

#endif // TESTFUNCTION_H_INCLUDED
```

testFunction.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "testFunction.h"

int addNum(int num){
    return num + num;
}
```

Comment: Include your build command in your question source. I suspect you're missing `testFunction.c` in the build line. i.e. `gcc Main.c testFunction.c`

Comment: Thank you @WhozCraig it's now working!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @WhozCraig cited, it is clear that you are lacking the function definition in main.c. Because of that, after compiling `main.c` There is no definition of the function `addNum`. ***If compilation of multiple files*** is what you are looking forward to knowing. There are several ways to link several files before compiling.

1. The most basic way is with command, in this case: `gcc Main.c testFunction.c -g -Wall`
2. The most concise way that you will almost always need in this type of scenario is to write a makefile.